# how do i make it so someone will fill out a form on my site, and then get redirected with to another form with the values already filled?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, forms, contacts

I am using a wp blog and I want leads to come in to go to be via email and then get refered to another website with the values already filled in?

I want to use php, but i will use anything that works.

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, when marking-up a form, you can specify default values.  So for example:

```
<form>
   <input name="firstName" value="John">
   <input name="lastName"  value="Doe">
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

So, once the user submits data from the first form, you can write the HTML in the second page with the user's information placed into the form already.  By default it will be there, but it could be edited again if he/she chooses.

I don't use WP, but I'm sure you can grab the data coming from the first form, then emit the same when generating the next page.